# How can I disable a category

Tags: category, status

The green bubble (status is enabled) next to the category items in the category overview suggests that you can disabled/enable the category.

Is that possible? And if so, how?

Comment: What's your use case that you want that feature?

Comment: I use a category list as a menu and need to remove some categories form the menu. I used a lightswitch field for it now and that works fine. I was just curious if there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: I think it's even cleaner to use a lightswitch "showInMenu". If you'd disable the category you wouldn't be able to use it at all, or you would get your categories with a (not sure if it exists for categories) property of `status('live', 'disabled')`, which I think is not elegant either.

Comment: But I see that in your case it would be nice to have that status light to indicate something! It would be really nice if you were able to set it to show the status of a specific property. Not only the category status (enabled / disabled) but also any other value of one of this category's fields. Want to make this a feature request to P&T, Vincent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I don't think you can disable categories with the current version of Craft. But you're right, it currently looks like that categories are prepared to get disabled.</s>

**Update:**

Categories now have their own edit pages in Craft 2.3, where you can set the status. And you can even set it on a batch from the category index page!

Comment: Nice feature! Exactly what I needed.